# Hazelcast and JCache: Custom serializers without using XML

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, jcache

Here is what I have:

- I am using Hazelcast v4.0.1
- I am using JCache v1.1.1
- I have several custom `Serializer`s that I want to use.

Here is my problem:

- My `Serializer`s have **constructor dependencies** so it's not possible to declare them via the .xml.
- JCache "automagically" binds itself to Hazelcast on startup using the .xml.
- Configuring the `Config` **afterwards** (i. e. adding the `Serializer`s to the config) does not result in the `Serializer`s being registred.

Solutions that I am looking for / that I have tried so far:

- Configuring the constructor dependencies into the .xml (can't be possible as these are specific runtime objects)
- Preventing the "automagical" bind from JCache, setting up the `HazelcastInstance` manually and the bind it to JCache somehow (don't know how to achieve this, don't even know if it's possible)
- Adding the `Serializer`s to the existing `HazelcastInstance`/`Config` (as said before, seems not to work)

**Question(s):**

**Is there any way to get it work? Am I missing something completely obvious? Am I using the frameworks wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you build your Hazelcast `Config` with custom `Serializer`s programmatically, here is one way to start a named Hazelcast embedded member and reference it by name:

```
    Config config = new Config();
    // apart from your config, setup the instance name
    config.setInstanceName("jcache-test");

    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

    // request the server-side caching provider
    // same method to bind by instance name also applies to client-side caching provider
    CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider(HazelcastCachingProvider.SERVER_CACHING_PROVIDER);

    // request the default CacheManager(url = null & ClassLoader = null)
    // indicating it should be bound to the named HazelcastInstance
    CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager(null, null,
            HazelcastCachingProvider.propertiesByInstanceName("jcache-test"));

    // use the CacheManager as usual
    Cache<String, String> cache = cacheManager.createCache("cache", new MutableConfiguration<>());
    cache.put("1", "a");
    System.out.println(cache.get("1"));
```

There are more ways to achieve binding a `CacheManager` to an explicitly configured `HazelcastInstance`, you can have a look at the examples in [this reference manual section](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#scoping-to-join-clusters).

As a sidenote, in general Hazelcast expects that the `Config` it is started with is final on startup. Mutations to the `Config` object after Hazelcast is started are not taken into account, except for specific data structure configuration that can be added after startup as discussed [here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#dynamically-adding-data-structure-configuration-on-a-cluster).